# как научить telegram бота на Node.js открывать ссылки

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

Подскажите как научить бота открывать ссылки которые ему скидывают в браузере автоматически

Comment: Для получения ответа вы предоставили недостаточно информации. Вам нужно что-бы бот открывал ссылки в браузере у вас на пк(там где запущен сам бот)?

Answer (score 1):

Так как я понимаю, вам нужно открыть ссылку которую вам прислали из диалога с ботом.
Тут все просто:

```js
// Получаете сообщение от пользователя...
// Парсите ответ чтобы получить  строку формата https://vk.com
// и выполняете этот код:

var childProcess = require('child_process');
var path = childProcess.execSync(`start "" "https://vk.com"`).toString();
```

отправленная ссылка откроется в браузере по умолчанию

Comment: Спасибо, сработало

Comment: Если мой ответ помог вам в решении вашего вопроса, вы можете отметить его как ответ для того чтобы другие люди у которых возникла эта ошибка смогли найти верное решение.