# Автоматическое открытие ссылки телеграм ботом

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой командой автоматически открыть ссылку, отправленную телеграм ботом на устройство?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1p7bEtTlxc', parse_mode='html')
    webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1p7bEtTlxc')
```

В данной реализации ссылка открывается на стороне сервера, а необходимо на стороне клиента.

Answer (score 1):

Это невозможно, API телеграма не разрешает боту открывать ссылки на стороне клиента. Можно только отправить ссылку, открыть её полльзователь должен сам.

Comment: На node.js вроде бы вот какое решение есть 
```// Получаете сообщение от пользователя...
// Парсите ответ чтобы получить  строку формата https://vk.com
// и выполняете этот код:

var childProcess = require('child_process');
var path = childProcess.execSync(`start "" "https://vk.com"`).toString();```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1142005/как-научить-telegram-бота-на-node-js-открывать-ссылки

Comment: это тоже самое открытие на стороне сервера

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.